# EKS Blueprints Kubernetes Addons - AWS Load Balancer Controller fails to deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform-provider-aws

I have tried running it multiple times but it fails. Not able to deploy load-balancer-controller addon
I have been able to deploy ebs and efs drivers addons. However failed to deploy, load-balancer-controller.

Error

```
Warning: Argument is deprecated │ │ with module.kubernetes_addons.module.aws_ebs_csi_driver[0].aws_eks_addon.aws_ebs_csi_driver[0], │ on .terraform/modules/kubernetes_addons/modules/kubernetes-addons/aws-ebs-csi-driver/main.tf line 21, in resource "aws_eks_addon" "aws_ebs_csi_driver": │ 21: resolve_conflicts = try(var.addon_config.resolve_conflicts, "OVERWRITE") │ │ The "resolve_conflicts" attribute can't be set to "PRESERVE" on initial resource creation. Use "resolve_conflicts_on_create" and/or "resolve_conflicts_on_update" instead _ _ │
Warning: Helm release "aws-load-balancer-controller" was created but has a failed status. Use the helm command to investigate the error, correct it, then run Terraform again. │ │ with module.kubernetes_addons.module.aws_load_balancer_controller[0].module.helm_addon.helm_release.addon[0], │ on .terraform/modules/kubernetes_addons/modules/kubernetes-addons/helm-addon/main.tf line 1, in resource "helm_release" "addon": │ 1: resource "helm_release" "addon" { │ _ _
Error: context deadline exceeded │ │ with module.kubernetes_addons.module.aws_load_balancer_controller[0].module.helm_addon.helm_release.addon[0], │ on .terraform/modules/kubernetes_addons/modules/kubernetes-addons/helm-addon/main.tf line 1, in resource "helm_release" "addon": │ 1: resource "helm_release" "addon" {
```

Kubernetes Addons Code

```
 module "kubernetes_addons" { source = "github.com/aws-ia/terraform-aws-eks-blueprints//modules/kubernetes-addons?ref=v4.32.1"

eks_cluster_id = module.eks_blueprints.eks_cluster_id
EKS Add-ons

enable_amazon_eks_aws_ebs_csi_driver = true
Self-managed Add-ons

enable_aws_efs_csi_driver = true
Optional aws_efs_csi_driver_helm_config

aws_efs_csi_driver_helm_config = { repository = "https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-efs-csi-driver/" version = "2.4.0" namespace = "kube-system" }

enable_aws_load_balancer_controller = true

}

provider "helm" { kubernetes { host = module.eks_blueprints.eks_cluster_endpoint cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.eks_blueprints.eks_cluster_certificate_authority_data) token = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster.token } }
```

Terraform version

```
Terraform v1.6.3
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/gavinbunney/kubectl v1.14.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v5.24.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/cloudinit v2.3.2
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/helm v2.11.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes v2.23.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local v2.4.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null v3.2.1
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tls v4.0.4
+ provider registry.terraform.io/terraform-aws-modules/http v2.4.1
```